# jenkins \ force project to run on specific slave with input parameter?

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

If I have job that invokes series of jobs in jenkins can I give them all parameter to tie them up to a specific server?

I talk about the "Restrict where this project can be run" that currently I need to specifiy in the project level (can I give it as input parameter?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be a able to create a string input parameter and then use that in the "Restrict where this project can be run" box. So if your string parameter was called TAG you would put `${TAG}` in the box.

You could then use the [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) Plugin to pass this to downstream jobs, essentially tying all of them to the same node.

Comment: " You should be a able to create a string input parameter and then use that in the "Restrict where this project can be run" box. So if your string parameter was called TAG you would put ${TAG} in the box.  "  This does not work in the default mode without any plugins .

Comment: That didn't work for me. The variable wasn't expanded and the job was waiting on ${AGENT} to be available. I have configured AGENT as a String parameter on the job.

Answer (score 8):

Use this plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin

You can provide a parameter to the job via either the ParameterizedTrigger or using the API and providing the node name (or label).